# Copy formula to last row of column A (In Sheets )

Tags: google-sheets

I am very new to using macro's in google sheets, and struggling to replicate easy VBA codes

I am trying to find the last row of column A, then add formulas to various columns and copy down to the last row.
In VBA it is as simple as `**("B2:B" & Lastrow).select`
However, this is not so straight forward.
I have found and manipulated the following, however it always goes to the very last row rather than the last row of data

```
var sheetName = "Week 1";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

   spreadsheet.getRange('E7').activate()
  .setFormula('=iferror(if(match($B7,Names,0),VLOOKUP($B7,Special,3,false),0),0)');

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(7, 5, lr-1);
  sheet.getRange('e7').copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

What needs to be done to the above so that it only fills down to the last row of data in column A

All and any help greatly appreciated

EDIT-
I have update the code, (Obviously wrongly) and added to the s/sheet under tools, copy on tab

```
    var sheetName = "Week 1";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var range = sheet.getRange("A7" + lastRow);
      if (range.getValue() !== "") {
        return lastRow;
      } else {
        return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
      }
    
      var lr = getLastDataRow(sheet,"A")
    
    //Saturday Formula
       spreadsheet.getRange('E7').activate()
      .setFormula('=iferror(if(match($B7,Names,0),VLOOKUP($B7,Special,3,false),0),0)');
var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(7, 5, lr-1);
  sheet.getRange('E7').copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

as between these two rows is a light bulb sayingabout unreachable code, and everything after and including Var = lr** is greyed out

```
}
    
      var lr = getLastDataRow(sheet,"A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction of your first code

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Week 1";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange('E7').setFormula('=iferror(if(match($B7,Names,0),VLOOKUP($B7,Special,3,false),0),0)');
  var lr= sheet.getRange('A7').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(7, 5, lr-6,1);
  sheet.getRange('E7').copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of var `lr = sheet.getLastRow();` , try

```
lr = sheet.getRange('A1').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()
```

change A by E if needed.

- edit : Change A1 by A7 si A4 and A6 are empty.

If you have discontinous value, prefer

```
function getLastDataRow(sheet,col) {
// col in letter
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }              
}
```

and

```
lr = getLastDataRow(sheet,"A")
```

Comment: Hi Mike, not sure the error, but only copies down 2 rows. I have added a copy of column A to the original question

Comment: this is because you have empty cells in between. I have completed my answer.

Comment: ok,  I presume then you go to the last row and scroll UP to find it?.

Comment: I have completed the answer

Comment: Apologies, did not see the edit. I have added the code to mine, however, now everything after  return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }      is greyed out?

Comment: Pls can you share your spreadsheet, if possible a sample one.

Comment: please try https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vVSoRg09N8mTivav9J95ksp8_oduOdspKzZSUz-46jk/edit#gid=1359003106

Comment: there is no named ranges!

Comment: Assuming there is a blank in A5 and A6, I replaced A1 with A7 in my answer. Both solutions work well. I cannot test setFormula because there are no named areas in your worksheet.

Comment: Apologies, updated and question edited

Comment: If lines of code are in grey color, the reason is that on previous lines you declared return.

Comment: Hi Mike. I got that, but not how to fix it. As said, new to this type of coding and hopefully not for much longer... I'll use the old code for now as that worked.  Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Go to the document, and see the script and the result : the function has been copied on each cell column E

Comment: Thank you, works fine. Just need to learn how :)